# How do I import the csv file without a garbage character showing up?

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import

I am trying to load my csv file into the database.

My CSV File

[image: My CSV File]

I used the below code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'DESKTOP/pet.csv' INTO TABLE pet 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(name,owner,species,sex,@birth,death)
set 
birth= str_to_date(@birth,'%d/%m/%Y');
```

I got the result as shown below:

Image of the result

[image]

In this image, there is some garbage value showing up before the first record in the table.
 ----´╗┐Fluffy

Please let me know how to ensure that the data is imported properly.

Comment: Could that be a Byte order mark?  Is the input a unicode file?

Comment: *My CSV File* This is NOT CSV file, this is a foto of some formatted table. *there is some garbage value showing up before the first record in the table* Save your CSV as UTF w/o BOM. Or skip this 3 bytes (`'EF BB BF'` for UTF-8, may be 2, 3 or 4, dependent by the encoding) from the value in SET clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three bytes of the file aren't garbage, they are UTF-8 Byte Order Marks

0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF

This is what we expect if someone edits a .csv file with Windows Notepad and does a Save As and selects Encoding: "UTF-8 with BOM"

The fix for this is to edit the file, and remove those first three bytes. Those three bytes are unnecessary. There are other tests that can pretty reliably identify a UTF-8 encoding.

(With the UTF-16 encoding, we do need the byte order marks to identify the endian-ness. But we don't have an endian-ness issue with UTF-8.)

Comment: Sure would make better sense if Oracle wrote a BOM handler into LOAD DATA INFILE in MySql.